# Displaying addressbook data acording to a certain search criteria

Tags: iphone

I need to display ABPeoplePickerNavigationController according to a certain search criteria. 
I pass a name from my view , i need to display the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController with that name only. How can i do this.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can not do this using the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.
You need to build your own UIViewController displaying the names matching your criteria. Finding matching contacts can be easily done using the C style Address Book API.

Comment: Its ok. Can u give me a reference to C style Address Book API

Comment: Here is the programming guide: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1